# How to go back to a version of a project (in a github repository)

Tags: github, repository, project

I have a repository that i (in the future may) want to revert back to a specific version incase of an issue.

How can i make backups/versions of my github repo (without having to manually save them to my harddisk)

Comment: To have versions of your project, you can separate working on your project to different branches. You have a release branch with different versions of your application and you can have a main/develop branch where you constantly work on the application.

Comment: ok, thanks @tomerpacific for explaining it for me :)

Comment: You can also [tag](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) commits.  I like to reserve branches for things that are actively being worked on.  Sample: `git tag -a v1.4 -m "my version 1.4, working on 2021-12-23"`

Comment: i mean, yea, but i dont use git because ive had bad times with it. i will check it out though. Also this question was already solved but thanks for the info